# Saving content of WebBrowser to file

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I got this little "explorer" that allow me to edit content of a local html file. I figured out how to use WebBrowser, innerHtml, and gettingelementbyid, from webbrowser to textboxes and back to webbrowser on change in textbox. It was pretty easy.

Now i need to save all changes back to opened and edited html file. I try this:

```
File.WriteAllText (adresbox1.Text,
                   webBrowser1.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml,
                   Encoding.GetEncoding(webBrowser1.Document.Encoding));
```

It is working but html code of output is changed:
All `id="idlabel"` and `class="divclass"` became `id=idlabel` and `class=divclass` - removing quotations - parser that crawl through those html files returns errors when i even change one character in wrong place of code.
Some of styles stop working (summary of paddings and margins in few places are smaller, you can see changes refreshing file that you keep opened in regular browser):

```
page-break-after:auto; page-break-inside: avoid;
```

before modifications they were working!
All tags became uppercase (`<head>` changed into `<HEAD>`), lot of "end of line" returns are removed (few code lines merged into one)
Missing `<doctype>` and more.

I try builtin method `showSaveAsDialog` - but ofcourse its not saving changes.

It is very important that code of pure tags stays intact. And i need a way to save this edited html (only innertext of some divs is added).

All suggestions will be good.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx) to write to the file.

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently back on this project, ad started from scratch. As far as i look `HtmlTextWriter` output whole code, it's hell of a work to do it, i don't see possibility to `HtmlTextWriter` wwrite just `innerText` to some `<divs>` - if i got already whole code in webbrowser control i just need to assure the proper syntax not to write whole html code from beggining.

Is there another way? I look for `webBrowser1.DocumentText` but it looks like code without changes i've made.