# How to change webBrowser DocumentText?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I know that there is lot of reports that `DocumentText` isn't changing but `Document.Body.innerHtml` is. 
I'm interested only in simply solution how to change it other way than ordinary string (replacing substrings). Is there a possibility to use `getElementById().innerText` ?
I want to open html file, make changes in and save it.

Comment: Or `SgmlReader` - see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11859613/168719

Comment: So what's wrong with `Document.Body.InnerHtml`/`OuterHtml`?

Comment: Code is altered, missing quotations marks, missing doctype - look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489718/saving-content-of-webbrowser-to-file